# Identifying which husband of my great grandmother my father came from

Tags: dna, research-methods, ancestry.com

My father was adopted.  I believe that I have located his mother.  Her father is my *GREAT GRANDMOTHER*'s first husband.  I have tested 3 1st cousins once removed??(Female 1 cm=673 on 29seg/female 2 cm=644 on 32seg/male cm=461 on 20.)  on that line.  My GREAT GRANDMOTHER*'s 2nd husband, I tested 1 first cousin once removed? or half first cousin once removed? (Female cm=615 on 27seg)?  How can I identify which one of these husbands is my great grandfather?

Comment: Are these 1C1R and half-1C1R to you, or to your father? Are the shared DNA amounts between you and the cousins, or between your father and the cousins? Are all of your shared DNA amounts correct?

Answer (score 4):

I can't directly answer your question based on the questions I asked in the comment on your question. However, I can still provide you some resources to help you out:

- [Blaine Bettinger](https://thegeneticgenealogist.com/)'s [Shared cM Project (with probabilities)](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4) allows you to plug in shared DNA amounts and see what the possible relationships are and how likely those relationships are.
- Read about Lauren McGuire's "[Simplified Visual DNA Comparisons](https://thegeneticgenealogist.com/2017/03/19/guest-post-the-mcguire-method-simplified-visual-dna-comparisons/)," shortly thereafter dubbed the McGuire Method.
- Leah Larkin, [The DNA Geek](http://thednageek.com/), has a seven+ part series of blog posts called "[Science the Heck Out of Your DNA](http://thednageek.com/science-the-heck-out-of-your-dna-part-1/)" which discusses using multiple relationship hypotheses and relationship probabilities to help determine the most likely relationship.
- In "[Science the Heck Out of Your DNA - Part 4](http://thednageek.com/science-the-heck-out-of-your-dna-part-4/)," Ms. Larkin introduces Jonny Perl's [Probability Test Tool](https://dnapainter.com/tools/prob1?m=%5B%5D).

And, always remember to back up your hypotheses with traditional genealogical methods and documentation.